# In Org-Agenda, how to show a complete file's summarized TODO status in one single line?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo

I often work in projects where all TODO items are bundled in one separate file. Often, I have quite a bit of TODO items which are then cluttering the agenda, while what I actually want is just a line meaning something like 'Still TODO items left in this-and-this-project'. Is there an elegant, built-in way to show such a kind of summarized status *in the agenda*? I imagine a line like `TODO this-file.org`.

One possible way to go would be to construct something like a summary item, which is then updated each time something in the file's todo tree is changed. That does feel quite hacky, though, and seems to require a bit of discipline (e.g. in organizing the layout of the project file, and not scheduling any sub-items, etc.). I would prefer a solution which relies on built-in functionality as much as possible. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is anything built-in that comes even close, so this will require some hashing out and discussion which probably makes this site inappropriate for the question. I would suggest asking on Reddit perhaps, or, better, on the Org mode mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably true. I just thought I might give a shout-out to those who are in the know. Sometimes it is surprising what actually *is* built-in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a built-in to summarize based on a category and TODO keywords for org-agenda views.[1]

However, if you structure projects as subtrees or nest the headings of the file in question with a parent header, you could utilize a combination of special TODO keywords and org tracking cookies to offer a summary line.

1. Define a todo-keyword like `PROJ` to signify a project (among other keywords you need to track work).

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "PROJ" "TODO" "|" "DONE")))
```

2. At the first level of any projects, add your PROJ keyword to the front and add a `[ / ]` or `[ % ]` to the end.

```
#+TITLE: project1.org
* PROJ Make a widget [ / ]
```

3. Add second level headers using a todo keyword.

```
#+TITLE: project1.org
* PROJ Make a widget [0/2]
** TODO Reticulate a spline
** TODO Save your work regularly
```

4. Call `org-agenda` either with the default `n` view for all todos, or with `m` and match your `PROJ` keyword. Your agenda view should contain the summary heading with the tracker cookie at the end.

[1]: That being said, if non-built-ins are acceptable, you may be able to use a group formatting string on a header if you utilized [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda). But this package is beyond my scope of knowledge.

Comment: That's the perfect solution! I actually do already organize the project-specific todo's in one big tree, so the only thing I need to change is to use the more specific `PROJ` keyword. That's indeed a nice idea I did not think about. So the idea is basically to have a "aggregated TODO" keyword. Thanks, I'll use that solution!